# Selecting the last row. Then perhaps iterating backwards

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

With all the awesome help I have had here, I thought I would ask for more.  I have a screen which as a random number of rows of clickable links.  I need to click the last row of this list.  Then find out if it's the right one.  If not, then go back, select the 2nd to last row, then 3rd to last row, etc.  Until I either find what I want, or run out of rows.

Unfortunately, every row has the same exact name. and I have to click it to find out if it's the row I want.

Here is an example of one of the rows:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" role="button" dojoattachpoint="subject" dir="ltr" aria-labelledby="taskrowsubjectcom_ibm_bpm_social_widgets_task_list_TaskRow_19" title="Click to work on the task">Request Full Quotes from Supplier: Supplier One</a>
```

The only difference is the number after the TaskRow.  Any assistance?

Here is some code previous to the row:

```
<div id="dueToday" class="bpm-task-list-category dijitTitlePane" title="" role="group" widgetid="dueToday" aria-label="Due Today (2)" style="display: block;">
<div class="dijitTitlePaneTitle dijitOpen" dojoattachpoint="titleBarNode" dojoattachevent="onclick:_onTitleClick, onkeypress:_onTitleKey">
<div class="dijitTitlePaneContentOuter" role="presentation" dojoattachpoint="hideNode">
<div class="dijitReset" role="presentation" dojoattachpoint="wipeNode" style="height: auto;">
<div id="dueToday_pane" class="dijitTitlePaneContentInner" role="presentation" dojoattachpoint="containerNode" aria-hidden="false">
<div>
<div id="com_ibm_bpm_social_widgets_task_list_TaskRow_2" class="bpm-social-task-row" widgetid="com_ibm_bpm_social_widgets_task_list_TaskRow_2" style="display: block;">
<div id="com_ibm_bpm_social_widgets_task_list_TaskRow_1" class="bpm-social-task-row" widgetid="com_ibm_bpm_social_widgets_task_list_TaskRow_1" style="display: block;">
<div class="bpm-social-task-box" dojoattachpoint="taskBoxAttach">
<div class="bpm-social-task-row-status-img-div">
<div class="bpm-social-task-row-data-div" role="listitem" tabindex="0" dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:toggle" dojoattachpoint="focusNode">
<div class="bpm-social-task-row-data-header">
<span class="bpm-social-task-row-data-subject">
<div id="taskrowsubjectcom_ibm_bpm_social_widgets_task_list_TaskRow_1" style="display:none" dojoattachpoint="headerLabel">Task subject</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" role="button" dojoattachpoint="subject" dir="ltr" aria-labelledby="taskrowsubjectcom_ibm_bpm_social_widgets_task_list_TaskRow_1" title="Click to work on the  task">Request Full Quotes from Supplier: Supplier One</a>
</span>
<div class="bpm-social-drop-down" wairole="button" style="display: block;" tabindex="0" dojoattachpoint="menuButton" role="button" aria-label="Actions" _dijitmenucom_ibm_bpm_social_widgets_actiondropdownmenu_41="1">
<span class="bpm-social-task-row-data-due" dojoattachpoint="due">
<span class="bpm-social-task-row-data-complete" dojoattachpoint="complete">
</div>
```

Thanks!
Greg

Comment: What are the rows? Are your links in a table? Please post more of the code.

Comment: I've added the code to the original comment.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It's far too messy to understand. Is this just one row? So your rows are divs? You're making it difficult to help you.

Comment: Also, unrelated, you have block-level elements (divs) inside of inline elements (spans) which is a no-no.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm the tester, not the developer of the code.  Yeah, the formatting really sucks when copying from Firebug.  I've gotten the line to iterate through the rows backwards '(//a[starts-with(@aria-labelledby, 'taskrowsubjectcom_ibm_bpm_social_widgets_task_list_')])[last()-X]' where X is a number starting from the end.  The only thing I'm stuck on now is how to know when I am at the first row to stop.

Comment: Well the code is ridiculous, and your question seems unclear. Why you can't just use a for-loop, is beyond me. Good luck. I can't make heads or tails of your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `:last-child` selector to do this:

```
a:last-child[aria-labelledby^='taskrowsubject']
```

With the more complete HTML, I was able to come up with this xpath:

```
(//a[contains(@aria-labelledby, 'TaskRow')])[last()]
```

Comment: That gets me the last element, then I can do [last()-X] where X is the number of elements from the end.  Only thing I am having troubles with now is getting a count of the elements for a for loop. `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@aria-labelledby, 'taskrowsubjectcom_ibm_bpm_social_widgets_task_list_')]")).size();` is always returning 1 even though there are 19 elements.

Comment: @GregMa Your code looks correct, and your xpath does too.  I'm not sure why that is returning the wrong value.

Comment: Aha, it was a timing thing.  It returns before it finishes the count.  Unfortunately I had to put a sleep in there.  But with that, it returns correctly!  Thank you!